# B2C Graph API - insufficient permissions even when Directory.ReadWrite.All is enabled

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to run 'change password' via Postman.

I get token using app id and secret

I can read data from the user profile no problem

I grant permissions to Graph API in Azure portal

I generate the token again, review it in jwt.io, sample

```
"Device.ReadWrite.All",
"Member.Read.Hidden",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All",
"Domain.ReadWrite.All",
"Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
"Application.ReadWrite.All"
],
```

I send

```
"password": "Test123456",
"forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
```

to `https://graph.windows.net/[tenant]/users/[user]api-version=1.6`.

I still get a fail with the following:

```
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
```

Comment: What is the value for `aud` in the token?

Comment: @juunas - 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

Comment: Umm, that's weird. It should normally be `https://graph.windows.net`. Try using that as the `resource` when you acquire the token.

Comment: not sure where to put it - this is what my URL in postman looks like currently https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/oauth2/token

Answer (score 0):

The change password permission isn't enabled in the same manner as the other permissions on the AD Graph API.

You need to set up a tenant admin local to the B2C tenant and then run the powershell commands as detailed here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-or-update-password-permissions-for-your-application).

Comment: I've already created that tenant, otherwise it simply isn't possible to even get the user profile information. I hadn't run the powershell commands tho, I'll look at that next

Comment: I spent a good few hours on this last night before finally finding the solution in the link above. The only difference might be that I'm working from a console app so I'm always opening in the context of that application rather than a logged in user.

Comment: Specifically, the service principal for the registered application must be assigned to the **User Account Administrator** role, which has a role identifier of **fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1**.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make sense to change the B2C (consumer)'s Password by the admin in the b2c tenant if it's not necessary.  Currently, you cannot use application permissions to reset user's password. Try to get the token with delegated permissions. Otherwise, you need to assign user account admin role to the service principal.